# I don't understand this definition of a derivation

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

Here is a definition of a derivation
[image]

How can we, for the first time, obtain a derivation with a hypothesis to use, for example, $(2\rightarrow)$?

More specifically, to prove, for example, $\vdash\phi\rightarrow(\psi\rightarrow\phi)$, I need to have a derivation with $\phi$ as a premise and $\psi\rightarrow\phi$ as a conclusion. But the only way to get $\psi\rightarrow\phi$ as a conclusion is to use a derivation with a premise (or a hypothesis, that's a little confusing, I'm not sure whether the author means the same thing for the words hypothesis and premise). But how can we introduce a derivation with a hypothesis for the first time according to the definition? I think the definition is not formal enough. There are no formal definitions of a premise, conclusion, or hypothesis above. Could someone clarify that, please?

P.S. Sorry for my English, I'm not a native speaker. Correct if there are some mistakes. I don't want to spend time polishing irrelevant things. Thank you.

Comment: Yes premise=hypothesis.

Comment: You write $\varphi$, then $\psi$, then iterate $\varphi$ then use $(\to \text I)$ to get $(\psi \to \varphi)$ discharging $\psi$, and then again.

Comment: Derivation is a tree of formulas where every node is either a premise or assumption or is derived from upper nodes by a rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can we introduce a derivation with a hypothesis for the first time according to the definition?

By the first rule: The formula $\phi$ in the definition is for hypotheses.

> I'm not sure whether the author means the same thing for the words hypothesis and premise

Often the terms "hypothesis" and "premise" are used interchangeably; "assumption" is another term.  To add to the confusion, there are two meanings of "premise" and "conclusion" in deduction systems, one which applies to derivations (i.e. the trees introduced in the definition you showed) and one which applies to rules (individual derivation steps (2) in the definition). In the context of natural deduction, it is possible to distinguish between:

A. For derivations:

- hypotheses, which are leave nodes in the tree (introduced by rule one), which may or may not be discharged later,
- premises, which appear on the left hand side of the turnstile in the derivability claim, and which may occur as undischarged hypotheses in the derivation.

Informally, hypotheses are temporary assumptions introduced in the proof procedure, whereas premises are the assumptions an argument finally depends on. (Though note that in classical logic, we may add arbitrary premises to the argument even when they are not actually needed in the proof, which is why the definition later will say that the undischarged hypotheses need only be a subset of the premises.)

The conclusion is then simply the root node of a derivation (the bottom most formula in the tree), corresponding to the right hand side of the turnstile.

B. For rules:

Premises are the formulas above the horizontal bar of a given rule, and the conclusion is the formula below. Hypotheses are separate from this: they are not rule applications but constitute an second kind of deduction step.

> It is unclear whether we can regard a one-element tree as containing only the hypothesis, only the conclusion, or both.

It contains only the hypothesis in the sense of which parts of the given definition of derivation (namely (1)), and only one premise and conclusion in the sense outlined first, i.e. leaf and root nodes of the tree. It does not contain any premises and conclusion in the second sense, as there are no rules (2)).

> without explicitly saying in (1) that, for example, ϕ is both D ϕ and ϕ D ϕ, we cannot use (2) to build new derivations, and thus have only atomic derivations.

Right; it is implicitly assumed that $\mathcal{D}$ may be empty, so $\dfrac{\phi \quad \phi'}{\phi \land \phi'}$ (without anything more above $\phi'$ and $\phi'$) constitutes a derivation, and we can build up from there. In this case, $\phi$ and $\phi'$ would be hypotheses as defined in (1), and at the same time, they are premises of the rule (2$\land$(i)). The $\mathcal{D}$ here essentially just means that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ have been legally obtained; they may be the result of some rule applications (2), but they may also be licensed by (1). We start the derivation with hypotheses (1) and then incrementally plug together the derivation tree from rules (2).

Comment: Many systems also have that assumptions/premises must remain undischarged, and hypotheses must be discharged. It’s a similar difference of convention between starting a proof from no assumptions on line 1 vs line 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem was the notation, but your explanation helped me collate everything. Now it's more or less clear

Comment: Just a clarifying question. When we use the rule $(1)$ for $\phi\in PROP$, can we consider $\phi$ as both the hypothesis and the conclusion? In other words, does $\phi$ match \begin{array}{l} \phi \\ D \\ \phi \end{array}?

Comment: @Seeker - yes; see clause (1) of def.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, but I wouldn't say it's that clear. There is only an informal definition of the premises (or hypotheses) and the conclusion of a rule, according to which the former is above the line and the latter is below. But in the case of $(1)$, we don't have the line. It is unclear whether we can regard a one-element tree as containing only the hypothesis, only the conclusion, or both.

Comment: @Seeker maybe... but you are mixing *derivations* and *rules*: the two are not the same. See page 29-30 for rules and page 32: "derivations have the form of trees." Then **Definition 2.4.1** gives the formal def of *derivation* (it is an inductive def) specifying that a derivation can be constructed from one or two already existing derivations applying one of the rules. Thus, how to start a derivation? using clause (1): "write down a formula $\varphi$".

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, in my opinion, $\bf{Definition\ 2.4.1}$ doesn't refer to the rules but rather to the notation introduced on page 32. The latter, in turn, uses the concepts of a derivation with a conclusion and one with hypotheses. However, those concepts are introduced there for the first time. Above, only the rules are discussed. Then, without explicitly saying in $(1)$ that, for example, $\phi$ is both $D\ \phi$ and $\phi\ D\ \phi$, we cannot use $(2)$ to build new derivations, and thus have only atomic derivations.

Comment: @Seeker Ah, I think I see the source of confusion now; "premises" and "conclusion" actually have two meanings in natural deduction. I expanded my post. Does this clarify things?

Comment: Also, could you tell us which book you got this from? Terminology and notation may differ slightly between differen authors.

Comment: @Natalie Clarius, yes, of course, the book is Logic and Structure by Dirk van Dalen. Thank you, Natalie. I will come back to your answer when reflecting again on the issue. I will also share my point of view.

Comment: @Natalie Clarius, in my opinion, in the atomic derivation $\phi$ introduced by $(1)$, we should consider $\phi$ as both a hypothesis and the conclusion (cause it is both a leaf and the root). Otherwise, we cannot apply $(2\land)$, for example, since it requires derivations with conclusions $\phi$ and $\psi$ according to the definition of the notation, which says that $\mathcal{D}\ \phi$ designates a derivation with the conclusion $\phi$.

Comment: @Seeker Yes, that's correct, in this case, $\phi$ is simulataneously a hypothesis (= an instance of construction (1)) and the premise and conclusion of the deduction tree.